# Java - differentiating between strings

Tags: java

Is there a number wildcard character in java? I'm opening a file and looking at a list of data and I need to differentiate between three pieces of information that start with "M". However, one of them has numbers directly following it and the other two have letters that follow. I was wondering if there was a way to check if there was a number after the letter with a wildcard character. I'm sure you could do this with ASCII, but I also am unsure of how to execute that.

EDIT: I'm still having issues, so here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class addSevTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("output6.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(br.readLine());
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(br.readLine());

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.contains("100%") || line.contains("70%") || matcher.find("[.][1-9]")){
            list.add(line);
            list.add("     2");
            list.add("\n");
            //System.out.println('Using String matches method: '+line.matches('.M'));
        }else if(line.startsWith("MDRALM")){
            list.add(line);
            list.add("     3");
            list.add("\n");
        }else if(line.startsWith("SOL") || line.startsWith("I/O") || line.startsWith("AH") || line.startsWith("LT")){
            continue;
        }else{
            list.add(line);
            list.add("     1");
            list.add("\n");
        }
    }

    /*while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        if(line.contains("CP")){
            list.add(line);
            list.add("\n");
        }
    }*/
    br.close();

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("addSevTest_O.txt"); 
        for(String str: list){
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking for Regex?

Comment: Regular expressions. See the API documentation of the [package `java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html).

Comment: You're looking for a Regex. You can use `Pattern`  and `Matcher` classes along with your Regex to evaluate the String.

Comment: Did we all mention Regex, already? :)

Comment: I think he wants Regex... ;)

Comment: You should really look into Regex. Lolz :)

Comment: I'm adding a different number after each piece of data, will Regex still help with this?

Comment: Yessir!  Regex will handle any combination of characters.

Comment: Once you catch the regex bug and realize how powerful they are for parsing strings, you'll never be able to turn back

Comment: Wow, regex looks amazing. Thanks guys, I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Regex is a language on it's own.  Whether you're programming ruby, javascript, java, or even C.. Regex, while will have little differences between languages... it is at it's core, a language in and of itself.  Have fun with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be best off using some simple regular expressions.
I found some basic tutorials you can skim through for the basics here:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/java-regular-expression-tutorial-with-examples.html

And a couple of tools to help you on your journey:

- http://regexpal.com/
- http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/

**EDIT**

In your added code, try replacing this:

```
    if(line.contains("100%") || line.contains("70%") || matcher.find("[.][1-9]"))
```

with this:

```
    if(line.contains("100%") || line.contains("70%") || line.matches("M[1-9]+.*"))
```

The `M` matches the first letter of the line.  `[1-9]` matches the digits, with the `+` meaning one or more.  `.*` means zero or more additional characters following the number will also match.

The `Pattern`/`Matcher` stuff you've got here is overkill for your purposes.

Comment: @CinCity add the code as an edit to your original question and we'll look

Comment: Its up there now, honestly, I have no idea whats going on.

Comment: @CinCity To start, pattern.compile should take a regular expression string.

Comment: Secondly, using `Pattern` and `Matcher` might be overkill here... a simple `string.matches(regex)` would probably serve your purposes - something like `string.toLowerCase().matches("M[0-9].*")` might do the trick

Comment: Oh, and this regex - `"[.][1-9]"` what are you trying to match with `[.]`?  Because that's going to match the literal character `'.'`

Comment: I'm just trying to look for data, Not match anything. I have a file that looks like this(just a sample of it):
    M2000,
    MTRM1205.01-1 
And I want to add "    2" to the M2000 and "     1" to the MTRM.

Comment: Totally works, many thanks my good sir. I'm going to have to study the regex harder.